# How to make mongodb returning an object with its @id and without href?

Tags: json, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

as said in title, i'm using mongodb for saving object and i have issues with my @id string.
The @id is send in a sort of wrapper when I want it in my object.
So, when reading my Json i obtain something like :

```
[
{
"id": null,
"login": "ASmith",
"firstName": "Alice",
"lastName": "Smith",
"fonctions": [
{
"id": null,
"name": "forgeron",
"access": [
{
"id": null,
"name": "Forge",
"role": "admin"
}
]
}
],
"access": [],
"telephone": "no telephone",
"fax": "no fax",
"filiale": "no filiale"
}
]
```

There is different kind of object but clearly see all the @id are null.
The fact is they are not send as a data.

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "utilisateur" : [ {
      "login": "ASmith",
      "firstName" : "Alice",
      "lastName" : "Smith",
      "fonctions" : [ {
        "name" : "forgeron",
        "access" : [ {
          "name" : "Forge",
          "role" : "admin"
        } ]
      } ],
      "access" : [ ],
      "telephone" : "no telephone",
      "fax" : "no fax",
      "filiale" : "no filiale",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://server:8081/utilisateur/5979957976a6f114b8760688"
        },
        "utilisateur" : {
          "href" : "http://server:8081/utilisateur/5979957976a6f114b8760688"
        }
      }
    },
```

but in the meta data as a link (for navigation purpose i suppose).

In my RestController i have something like :

```
@RequestMapping("utilisateurs")
    public Collection<Utilisateur> hi() {
        return ( utilisateurRepo.getUtilisateurs().getContent());
    }
```

Which "unwrap" the data, losing this way my @ids...
So how could i do for get just a simple JSON with all my data and no wrapper or other crap ?
I search a day but found nobody with this kind of problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally for my case, the fact was my id was not send back because mongo save it has "_id" for mongo purpose.
So if you record your id as "_id", the link is safe and mongo send it back.

EDIT : Well, at the end the problem is springRest don't WANT TO expose ids.
So you have to ask him to do so as explain here : https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-161